# does "of which" refer back to "spirit land" or "happier ones in the spirit land"?

Tags: grammar

does "of which" refer back to "spirit land" or "happier ones in the spirit land"?

And when the earthly years have ended may we continue to spend still
happier ones in the spirit land, glimpses **of which** I am occasionally
getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means glimpses of "happier years in the spirit land".

There is a double call-back here - first it speaks of "years" spent on the earth, but rather than repeat the word it then says "*happier ones*", the "ones" meaning "*years*".